# Are certain source models better suited for particular tasks?

Tags: classification, computer-vision, transfer-learning

I have the task of classifying medical images in a binary fashion. I plan on using transfer learning on a CNN but don't know what source model would be best to fine tune for this task.

Are certain source models better suited for particular tasks? If so, how would I go about determining which source model would be best for my particular task?

I have a test set of around 2,500 labeled image.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use a pre-trained model, you will definitely benefit if it was trained on similar data, as you are in a "cross-task" transfer learning setting.

You can start by exploring [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/) which is, among other things, a large repository of pre-trained models. Try to find a model that was trained on similar images, regardless of the task. Then you can fine-tune this model for the specific task you wish to solve using your own labeled images.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and your kind words. Although, I found a distinct lack of models trained on medical imaging of any kind. Perhaps I've researching the models or datasets improperly?

Comment: @seth This kind of data can be difficult to share for privacy reasons... If you don't find something similar enough, you can always use a model pre-trained on the ImageNet dataset, as it provides a good base for a variety of data and tasks.